# ALTER LOGIN gives Incorrect Syntax near 'PASSWORD' error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that can be called to change the password of a SQL Server 2008 Login.  When I run the procedure, I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'PASSWORD'.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_update_user]
(
    @arg1       varchar(255) = null,
    @arg2       varchar(255) = null
) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);

SET @SQLString = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @arg1 + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @arg2 + '''';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString

END
```

I am calling the procedure with `exec proc_update_user 'Billy' , 'newPassword';`
If I run the following query in SQL Server Management Studio, the user is updated without issues:

```
ALTER LOGIN Billy WITH PASSWORD = 'newPassword';
```

Any idea why my procedure is giving the error?

**Edit:**
This is the code I use to call the stored procedure in C++.  I added this to compare to one of the answers given.  I don't think my problem lies in my C++ code because executing `exec proc_update_user 'Billy' , 'newPassword'` in management studio is giving me the error.  The stored procedure obviously doesn't work in my application either.

```
strcpy(szProcName,"{?=call dbo.proc_update_user(?,?)}");
rc=SQLPrepare(sqlc.g_hstmt,(SQLCHAR*)szProcName,(SQLINTEGER)strlen(szProcName));
            rc=SQLBindParameter(sqlc.g_hstmt,1,SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER,0,0,
                (SQLPOINTER) &test_val,0,&m_cbRetValue);
rc=SQLBindParameter(sqlc.g_hstmt,2,SQL_PARAM_INPUT,SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR,sizeof(Login_Name),0,
                Login_Name,sizeof(Login_Name),&Login_Name_Len);
rc=SQLBindParameter(sqlc.g_hstmt,3,SQL_PARAM_INPUT,SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR,sizeof(Password),0,
                Password,sizeof(Password),&Password_Len);
rc = SQLExecute(sqlc.g_hstmt);
```

Comment: You should update your procedure to use parameterized dynamic sql to avoid sql inejction. You have them nicely parameterized from your code but your procedure is still vulnerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) you have to also pass OLD_PASSWORD parameter.

```
ALTER LOGIN myUser WITH 
    PASSWORD = 'newPassword' 
    OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpass';
GO
```

So now your SP will look like this-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_update_user]
(
    @arg1       varchar(255) = null,
    @arg2       varchar(255) = null,
    @oldpass varchar(255) = null,
) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);

SET @SQLString = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @arg1 + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@arg2, '''') + ' OLD_PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@oldpass, '''');
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString

END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have shown that I tried that in my question, because I did.  It however, gives the same error.

Comment: If the dynamic sql was parameterized this would be an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing one `'` ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_update_user]
(
    @arg1       varchar(255) = null,
    @arg2       varchar(255) = null
) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);

SET @SQLString = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @arg1 + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @arg2 + ''';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString

END
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work.  When I remove the last single quote, it turns the rest of my code into "quoted (red) text".  I need four at the end.  `'       '' --these two escape as one single quote          '`

Comment: yes I've noticed that. gimme another change to catch the problem then